# debian/changelog illegal package name

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, changelog

I am a deb file packaging newbie, and I am getting this warning when I run dch (from devtools)
to make the changelog. I have tried several package names, but I still get this warning. The changelog is generated, but the package name isn't inserted. What am I doing wrong?

```
$dch --create -v 1.0.8 --package libXau
dch warning: illegal package name used with --package: libXau
dch: Did you see that warning?  Press RETURN to continue...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First- libxau6 1.0.8 is already in Debian; are you sure you don't just want to use the one that's already packaged- at least as a starting point?

But to answer your question, Debian package names are [not allowed to have uppercase letters](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Source). The `dch` tool knows about that rule and is trying to save you. Just do "`libxau`" instead of "`libXau`" and you should be fine.

Finally, if you're packaging something for others to use and not just yourself, you may want to become familiar with the good-debian-citizen rules about library packaging, like "it's a good idea to have a package name based on the library `SONAME`, so the package name can change anytime the `SONAME` changes." One starting point in Debian Policy itself is https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html , although there are friendlier intros out there.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Im not clear on SONAME, is that a variable in one of the debtools scripts or something I would add in on my own later?

Comment: It's a feature of your library. Read e.g. the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname)